# how to show total values above in stackbar MPAndroid Chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Is there a simple way to the display the the sum of a stacked bar above it ?
the values are displayed for each area, but I only want to see total also for the entire stacked bar.

Answer (score 1):

Use the StackedValueFormatter

Code will look like:

stackChart.getBarData().setValueFormatter(new StackedValueFormatter(false,"suffix",0));

The first parameter defines whether to show both labels (true) or to show only the total (false).  The second parameter is a suffix to append to the value and the third is the number of decimal places to show.

Documentation [here](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is the solution!

Comment: As per the document I see, StackedValueFormatter is used only for 


A formatter specifically for stacked BarChart that allows to specify whether the all stack values or just the top value should be drawn

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this and it looks like there's currently no way to reliably get values to be just on top.  The StackedValueFormatter doesn't deal with 0 or duplicated values properly.  This is something that would have to be fixed via API change.