# Stacked Barchart: Display only sum of each stack

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart, formatter, stacked-chart

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188843/how-to-show-total-values-above-in-stackbar-mpandroid-chart), it's necesarry to use the `StackedValueFormatter` in order to only display the total sum of every stack on top of the bar.

However, it turns out that the `StackedValueFormatter` is deprecated.

The function `getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler)` is no longer available and thus, the solution is no longer valid.

Is there are new solution which replaces the `StackedValueFormatter`.

The endresult should look like this:

[image: endresult]

Answer (score 0):

The following will prevent rendering of the items on the inside of the colored stacks; I don't know if this will affect the topmost number: I'm just experimenting with the same goal.

```
    BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
    data.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
            return "";
        }
    });
```